# Please tell me where I am

Tags: rebus

Can you tell me where I am?

A simple Rebus

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in:

> Toronto

Because:

> Reading II as Roman numerals for 2, which sounds like "to", you have:
>  "To-r" on "to"